# Pronouncing "00's" (as in 2000's)

Tags: time, dates, pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the name of the first decade in a century?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/997/what-is-the-name-of-the-first-decade-in-a-century)

When talking about decades in the 20th century, it is customary to refer to them using only the last two digits. For example, the 1990's are typically referred to by "90's", and so on.

As we move into the 21st century, I've noticed that similar conventions are being applied. The first decade has been called both "2000's" and "00's". However, while pronouncing something like "90's" is relatively simple, there is no clear way to pronounce "00's".

None of the possible pronunciations I've considered seem correct, so **what is the right way to pronounce "00's"?**

Comment: *I'm loving* this question!!