# The 00s equivalent for "so 90s"

Tags: expressions

When you wanted to state that something belongs to a previous era's fashion at the turn of the century you could say so 90s or so 20th century.

Now when you want to say that something belongs in the 200xs what would you say?
(So zeros or so [aughts](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/997/what-is-the-name-of-the-first-decade-in-a-century) just doesn't sound right.)

Edit: This is **not** a duplicate of [What is the name of the first decade in a century?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/997/what-is-the-name-of-the-first-decade-in-a-century)

Comment: This question is relevant to at least 10% of the years (even more if you want to say something belongs to an even older decade), so it doesn't seem to fall under the "too localized" close rule.

Comment: What's wrong with "so 2000"?

Comment: I added a link to the question that this is a supposedly a duplicate of myself. This is not exactly the same question - here I am asking for an expression, not simply a name for the previous decade.

Comment: @OptimalCynic Other than it being in French and not English, it refers to the end of the century, not the beginning.

Comment: @nico So 2000 refers to a single year. So 2000s may refer to the entire millennium. Perhaps **So 2000s and 00s** would work.

Comment: @Danny: I think it would be pretty clear from the context. If I'm telling you now "it's so 2000s" I'm clearly not referring to the whole millennium... so you are good to use it until year 3000!

Comment: @nico I'll try it out and see if people get it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideas I had:

1. "So 2Ks", however, like "so 2000s" this may refer to the entire millennium.
2. "So last decade", which is good until 2020.
3. And a new idea: "so 2000s and 0s".

Comment: Mm... sounds like “soda case”.

Comment: @tchrist: "In the year soda-case oh-nine..."

Comment: Does that mean you think this expression is catchy? :-)

Comment: If anyone has a better idea, vote to reopen the question and then post an answer.

Answer (score 10):

The [*noughties*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/noughties?q=noughties) is sometimes used — aparently primarily BrE.  It's a clumsy term but...

Comment: Found that in the linked question (see the aughts link), however, it too just doesn't sound right - especially preceded by "so".

Comment: I'm confused. Where does the word originates from? If it'd be *zeros-ties*, I'd understand but the *nough* part is very unclear to me. I read into it that the decade was **naughty**, hehe...

Comment: @KonradViltersten "Nought" also means "zero" - but it is also partly a pun on "naughty".

Comment: Well, there you see... I learned a new word today. +1 for creative answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are going for a lighthearted remark, you could try:

> ***So turn-of-the-century.***

I think that might be particularly effective, because, a mere 20 years ago, the same phrase was being used to describe the time period around 1900.

Comment: I don't think *turn-of-the-century* works at all today for the decade 2000-2009. Twenty years ago it was being used to refer to a period *ninety* years earlier. I seriously doubt the expression would have been used in 1912 to refer to the immediately-preceding decade.

Comment: @Fumble: That's the point–it's meant to be wry humor. Where "that's so turn-of-the-century" used to mean something very different–something long ago, in the age of our grandparents–it suddenly means something that's barely 10 years old.  Yet with the rapid changes in technology, things become out-of-date much more quickly. I've actually used this expression several times, in contexts such as: "Oh, **email**! That's **so** turn-of-the-century," as a way to emphasize how email is falling out of fashion in favor of texting and social networks. Usually, it works. Maybe I should've elaborated more.

Comment: oic - yes, I agree that the pace of change really *is* hotting up as we approach [technological singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity). Which Wikipedia defines as the time when "greater-than-human intelligence" arrives, but which I define as the time when new things are arriving so fast you'll go to bed one night knowing approximately the state of human knowledge and control of our environment, but by the time you wake up next day, all that will be no more than "ancient history".

Comment: @Fumble: Yes, exactly. Advertisers have played on this phenomenon, too, showing, e.g., someone walking out of a store with a new electronic gadget, only to spot a billboard advertising an even newer version, even as the customer is still standing in the store parking lot.

Comment: This expression could be good for 90 years, however, I am not sure it is catchy enough.

Comment: I agree; although your post doesn't really provide much of a context for what you want. If you were writing a research paper, my suggestion is entirely inappropriate. If you were just looking to make an amusing remark at a dinner party, this might be a good way to do it. Absent a context, though, you'll get a range of varied answers, each with its own plausable usage.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a term that has been universally accepted for this. So I would tend toward:

> ***So ten years ago***

Comment: "So last decade" would sound better, since it is referring to a ten year range and not a specific year. However, I was hoping for a 2000 decade specific term.

Comment: That is a relative term so it won't refer to the 00's ten years from now.

Comment: I don't disagree. So in ten years you can start saying, "So twenty years ago."  As I said, I don't know of any term that has been universally adopted.

Comment: It's both relative to the current point of time (as others pointed out) **and** it points to a certain year, not the whole decade, in my view.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, use the evergreen

> That's so passé

*[That style of music is now considered passé.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pass%C3%A9)*

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/5pilh9/thats_so_2000s/) has a page entitled

> That's **so 2000s**

Back in 2013, [8 Tracks Radio](https://8tracks.com/anap-prates/that-s-so-2000s) was already talking about the 2000s as if it were the Neolithic era

> That's **soooo 2000s**!

In the realm of fashion, cite the name of the designer who is no longer TD (to die).

> “We would sit and scroll through what used to be Style.com and click through the runway shows. We would crack ourselves up and be like, **‘That's so 2000s Galliano**, what were they thinking!’
>
> *[Diet Prada Puts Fashion Knock-offs on Blast on Instagram](http://www.mandatory.com/living/1307731-diet-prada-puts-fashion-knock-offs-blast-instagram)*
> <sub>Miss Rosen, Aug 7th, 2017</sub>

Comment: I'm amazed. When I saw the age of the question, I figured any new answer would be saying "the now generally accepted term is **the noughties**". But you're suggesting something different!

Comment: @AndyT I'm not "suggesting", these are actual instances taken from the net. The OP also wants to use it in the phrase "so" . *That's so the noughties* doesn't sound so great.

Comment: @AndyT the last link [only has 31 results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22that%27s+so+noughties%22&rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=v1O7Wo7qEczzUpz5q8AC&start=30&sa=N&biw=1309&bih=619), you got to click the page numbers to see the actual number. Google's estimates must always been taken with a sack load of salt :( Whereas for the first link, ["that's so 2000s"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22that%27s+so+2000s%22&rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=8VS7WqnjAsGoUozdlZAC&start=50&sa=N&biw=1309&bih=619) the actual number is 58

Comment: :O Mind blown! I had no idea the estimate could be so far off!

Comment: @AndyT it's also my understanding that American speakers generally do not favo(u)r "noughties".

Answer (score 0):

I would say, "so last decade." Which would refer to the '00s.

Comment: Yes, but that is a relative term so it won't refer to the 00's ten years from now.

Comment: So last decade, as I previously wrote in a comment sounds good, however, it is a relative term as FWFD stated.

Answer (score 0):

I rather like to use ***antemillennial***, but that only applies to the year 2000 itself, not to the ones following it.

Comment: Well, then, you can always use _antecentennial_ for the next 900 years :^)

Comment: I thought *ante* meant *prior to*, making the term *antemillennial* equialent to the 90s (or even any shorter/longer period that a decade taking place **before the millennium shift**). What do I miss?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I don’t think you missed anything. *Antemillennial* just means before the (turn of the) millennium, so before 2001.