# When talking about decades, is it correct to write "90's" with an apostrophe?

Tags: numbers, apostrophe

When referring to decades such as the nineties, is it correct to write 90's with an apostrophe?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. "Correct" in such matters depends on which style guide you are using. There is no universal standard.

Comment: Have a look also at: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141112/what-is-the-name-for-the-second-decade-in-a-century

Comment: Ah right, thanks :) Is the plural of things like 'CD' with or without an apostrophe, or does that also vary according to style guides?

Comment: [Plurals of acronyms, letters, numbers — use an apostrophe or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not). We have a [search feature](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=acronym%20plural%20apostrophe).