# Words for refering to the first and second decade of the new century, a la 20s or 30s

Tags: single-word-requests

How can we refer to the first or the second decade the new century, a la 20s or 30s?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the name of the first decade in a century?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/997/what-is-the-name-of-the-first-decade-in-a-century)

Comment: Also a duplicate of [What is the name for the second decade in a century?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/141112/191178)

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the first decade then you can use 'noughties'

> [**noughties** : the period of years between 00 and 10 in any century, usually 2000–2010](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/noughties)

There is no consensus on the best word to use as they do not flow as easily as 'twenties', 'thirties', etc.

The period from 1910-1919 has been referred to as the 'nineteen-tens' or 'teens', although there is no universally accepted term for the 2000-2009 decade.

'Twenty-tens' or 'Two thousand tens' is generally used at present however this is likely to change as this decade becomes referred to historically.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve heard “the aughts” or “the two thousands” or “the twenty-o’s” for the decade 2000-2009.

Also, “the two thousand tens” or “the twenty-tens” for the decade 2010-2019.

Comment: "The first quarter of the 21st century" would encompass the years from 2000 to 2025 or thereabouts.  When we say "the '20s" or "the '30s" these days, we're generally referring to the 1920s and 1930s, not the 1820s or 1830s or the corresponding years in other centuries.

Comment: An interesting question is: When will people start using “the 20s”, “the 30s”, etc. to refer to decades in this century instead of the last century?