# What is the equivalent of "noughties" and "tweens" for 1900-1920?

Tags: etymology, british-english, history

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the name of the first decade in a century?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/997/what-is-the-name-of-the-first-decade-in-a-century)
>   [“nineteen-hundreds”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/941/nineteen-hundreds)

I have often heard the period between 2000-2010 called the "noughties", and the period between 2010-2020 as the "tweens". Was there an equivalent of this in the 20th century (or earlier!), or is this a modern invention?

Should we be using another, "correct" term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decade of 1900 to 1909 was known as the aughts.

The noughties were the result of referring to zero as O (oh) or nought in many countries.

I am not sure about the period between 1910 to 1919 though. I have not heard of the tweens being used for this decade either.

I am of the opinion that a tween is generally a person who is in between the age group of 10 to 12. Not a child. Not yet a teen.

So, maybe the tweens you came across might have actually been referring to the period from 2010 to 2012 which we are now a part of.

Please provide reference to tweens you might have come across.

Comment: I had only heard it used verbally, although looking into it further it looks like it may have been "teens" - it seems to be [fairly common](http://www.google.com/search?tbs=bks%3A1&tbo=1&q=%22born+in+the+teens%22&btnG=Search+Books)