# What time period does "1600s" refer to?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, semantics, dates

I've used the form "XX00s" to mean a century, as in *How poverty affected Britain in the late 1800s* or *In the 1600s the tensions between the crown and parliament came to a head*

And I use "XXX0s" to mean a decade, as in *The 1990s saw two wars*

This is fine until I need to refer to the first decade of a century. *In the 1800s* could mean 1800-1809 or 1800-1899 according to my usage.

What is the correct meaning of "In the 1600s"? I checked the Chicago Style Guide but it doesn't clarify this case. And Wikipedia disambiguates both meanings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1800s

Comment: I would never ever guess that 1600s meant 1600-1609.

Comment: It's ambiguous -- usually means the entire century, but may just refer to the decade.  A lot depends on context.

Comment: @Jim But wouldn't you deduce that meaning if the following text talked about the 1610s and the 1620s? As _Hot Licks_ says it depends on the context.

Comment: @KillingTime - Of course if it was it a table of decades or something. But OP says he uses both.  And in text such as: How poverty affected Britain in the late 1800s.  Tensions started to rise in the 1890s and peaked in the 1900s. I’d still interpret as 1800-1899 and 1900-1999.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/q/941/191178

Comment: My late father. born in 1907, used to refer to the decade of his birth as 'the 1900s'. I found it quite puzzling when I first came across people who called the whole of the 19th century 'the 1800s'.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue only to be resolved by contextual definition.

For example, 1900s is decadal in the following fashion account, which clearly defines decades in the century of 1900 onwards, with 1900s defined as 1900 to 1910.

> [Victoria and Albert Museum](http://www.vam.ac.uk/content/articles/h/history-of-fashion-1900-1970/)

On the other hand, 1800s refers to the whole century in:

> [USCIS](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/lesson-plans/Civil_War_handouts.pdf)

Such examples confirm the ambiguity you point to in Wikipedia. This ambiguity therefore seems inherent in the usage and cannot be removed by universal definition, only by specific contextual definition wherever it is encountered.

This means that when you use 1900s 1800s etc you should define which meaning you wish to attach to the term.

Comment: To the OP - because of this inescapable ambiguity, if you're writng about the first decade of a century and you want to be clear, your best bet is to be explicit - e.g. "in the first decade of the 1600s"

Comment: @user888379 Thanks, I was trying to formulate rules to do accurate date extraction from text for this case, but looks like I will have to extract and assign two meanings.